# Add string after a certain string in the same line in a text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, scripting

I have been trying to add a string in the same line in a text file. I have used following method.

```
sed -i "s/\bmembers\b/& \t$host,/" printer.cfg
```

It will add a string after members string and also it will add tab in order to make it proper.

I will get result like this,

```
define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name  HOSTGROUP ONE   
alias       Host Group 1 Printers
members     foo0, foo1, bar2, foo2, bar3
}
```

Where foo0 is my added string using above sed.

But the problem is there is one text file, that contains many "members" string.

e.g.

```
define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name  HOSTGROUP ONE   
alias       Host Group 1 Printers
members     foo1, bar2, foo2, bar3
}

define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name  HOSTGROUP TWO
alias       2nd Host Group
members     example1, example3, example2
}
```

In this above example, I want to add string ONLY in first para (hostgroup_name HOSTGROUP ONE). In this case, How can I refer hostgroup_name and add text after "members" string with one tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

***sed*** approach:

```
sed "0,/members/{s/\bmembers */&$host, /}" printer.cfg
```

- `0,/members/` - address range occupying a range of lines starting from the 1st line till the first occurrence of `members` pattern

---

***awk*** approach:

```
awk -v h=$host '!f && /members /{ $2=sprintf("%8s, %s",h,$2); f=1 }1' printer.cfg
```

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name  HOSTGROUP ONE   
alias       Host Group 1 Printers
members     foo0, foo1, bar2, foo2, bar3
}

define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name  HOSTGROUP TWO
alias       2nd Host Group
members     example1, example3, example2
}
```

Comment: @BuvaneshKumar, you're welcome

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest, Is there any way to add the string without referring number? Because the text file content will be larger day by day. Is it possible to refer "hostgroup_name" and add string in members line?

Comment: @BuvaneshKumar, `/hostgroup_name/,/members/` - this will capture all ranges within a file and cause to multiple replacements. So this `0,/members/` is suitable to replace only once. Also, consider my awk approach

Comment: I mean the variable (HOSTGROUP ONE) I allocated for hostgroup_name is constant. It will not change. So is there any way we can refer both that variable and members?

Comment: @BuvaneshKumar, yes, in that case you can apply `/hostgroup_name *HOSTGROUP ONE/,/members/`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the 3-step process of selecting, storing, and shaping the range of interest data. The final task of printing to stdout is an autotask of `sed`.

```
host='Foo_0';
sed -Ee '

   # Step-1: SELECT RANGE
   /^define hostgroup[{]/,/^[}]/!b

   # Step-2: SAVE RANGE DATA
   H; /^define hostgroup[{]/h; /^[}]/!d

   # Step-3: SHAPE RANGE DATA
   g;/\nhostgroup_name\s+HOSTGROUP ONE/s/\nmembers\s+/&'"${host}"', /

' printer.cfg
```